# TitleHeaderForSection

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

i want a titleHeaderForInSection but i'm doing something wrong my code:

```
 self.List = [[NSArray alloc]
                   initWithObjects: 
                   @"2", 

                   nil];


    self.List2 = [[NSArray alloc]
                   initWithObjects: 
                   @"1", 

                   nil];
```

and;

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.List objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        cell.textLabel.text = [self.List2 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];




    }
    return cell; 
}
```

Is something like this possible? It's now showing me only '1'

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.List objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
cell.textLabel.text = [self.List2 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

A screenshot:

![enter image description here][1]

The problem is that under TitleHeaderForSection 'A' i want '2' and under TitleHeaderForSection 'B' i want the number 1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uD2Q.png

Edit:

i'm using the code but a strange thing i have;

```
    self.List = [[NSArray alloc]
                       initWithObjects: 
    @"1", 
    @"2", 
    @"3", 
    @"4", 
                       nil];


        self.List2 = [[NSArray alloc]
                       initWithObjects: 
     @"5", 
     @"6", 
     @"7", 
     @"8", 
 nil];
       self.List3 = [[NSArray alloc]
                       initWithObjects: 
    @"9", 
    @"10", 
    @"11", 
    @"12", 
 nil];
       self.List4 = [[NSArray alloc]
                       initWithObjects: 
    @"13",
    @"14", 
    @"15", 
    @"16",  
 nil];
```

and:

```
 if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.List objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 1)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.List2 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];       
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 2)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.List3 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];       
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 4)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.List4 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];       
        }
```

//

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.


     switch (section) {

         case 0:
             return [self.List count];

         case 1:
             return [self.List2 count];

         case 2:
             return [self.List3 count];

         case 3:
             return [self.List4 count];

         default:
             return 0;
     }


}
```

But after TitleHeaderForSection 'B' this is wat happend instead of 9/10/11/12 and under D 13/14/15/16 it's showing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuYOx.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are messing this up

do this

```
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
cell.textLabel.text = [self.List objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]];

}
else
{
cell.textLabel.text = [self.List2 objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]];
}
```

Right now you first assign the value 2
in line

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.List objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

and then 1

in this line

```
cell.textLabel.text = [self.List2 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

So in the end you always get 1.

Comment: Correct. Also, the setting of the label text has to be moved outside the `if (cell == nil)` block

Comment: try to NSlog the array counts in `numberOfRowsInSection`